Is there a technical name for functions that end in Q?
Just out of curiosity: is there a technical name for Mathematica/Wolfram functions that end in Q? Could they be called test functions or predicate functions, perhaps?
Examples of such functions include:
MemberQ[list, form]
FreeQ[list, form]
SubsetQ[list1, list2]
AssociationQ[expr]
KeyExistsQ[assoc, key]
StringMatchQ["string", patt]
StringContainsQ["string", patt]
StringFreeQ["string", patt]

... among many, many others.

I teach my students "Query" functions... easy to remember, whether technically correct or not!

Obligatory non-example: LegendreQ

@ilian LegendreQ[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adrien-Marie_Legendre] evaluates to True.

Wolfram Reference calls them (and a few other functions) "Testing Expressions" and says: [...] The Wolfram Language provides a rich collection of functions to test expressions. Functions that "ask a question" have names that end in Q. They return True for an explicit true answer, and False otherwise.. So you could also call them "question functions".

Don't forget EllipticNomeQ, too.

MarcumQ also.

Just looked through all Q functions and these are the ones that aren't the standard query functions: BilateralHypergeometricPFQ, EllipticNomeQ, HypergeometricPFQ, InverseEllipticNomeQ, LegendreQ, MarcumQ, PartitionsQ, QHypergeometricPFQ.

I used to think of them as question functions, but like @David, I've called them query functions for a while, having picked this up long ago from other Mathematica users. Unfortunately, we now have Query[],  which makes the term ambiguous. I think of the Q as standing in for a question mark. I now call them Q functions, as in Q&A. Since nowadays everybody abbreviates everything with initialese, LOL, it seems appropriate.
Interestingly, version 1 did not give a rationale for the "...convention that functions of this kind [for testing properties of expressions] whose names end with the letter Q are set up to give False if their tests are not explicitly satisfied." But in version 2, the rationale cited in Kevin Dietrich's comment was introduced, altering the above sentence to read: "It is a convention that functions of this kind have names that end with the letter Q, indicating that they 'ask a question'." That's probably why I started off thinking in terms of "question."
I think of Positive and Negative as predicate functions, too, which are not Q functions, though I sometimes wish they were. And GreaterEqual etc. are definitely predicates. But these do not evaluate to True or False unless the predicate is explicitly so at the time of evaluation. You could think of the Q like a Krispy-Kreme hot-now-donuts sign, True if it's on, False if it's not worth stopping:
stopForDonuts[loc_GeoPosition : Here, mmm_Integer : 12] := 
  (nDonuts -= mmm) /;
 KrispyKremeQ[loc] && nDonuts >= mmm && Positive[mmm];
stopForDonuts[___] := $Failed;


I call these "predicate functions" because they always return either True or False
